# is there a way to render form helpers dynamically via ajax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

The problem is:

I need to render a collection of checkboxes via ajax, so I have this:

```
$("#imovel_tipo_imovel_id").on "change", ->
    $.get("/admin/caracteristicas", { tipo_imovel_id: $(this).val() })
```

When I change a select value, it will hit my controller and render back a collection of checkboxes. The problem is that the partial I need to render must be inside a form and sent back to a different controller.

```
= simple_nested_form_for @imovel do |f|
  .caracteristicas
    = render 'my_partial', f: f
```

the partial

```
= f.simple_fields_for :caracteristicas_imovel do |c|
  = c.collection_check_boxes :caracteristica_id_in, @caracteristicas, :id, :descricao
```

the js.erb responde:

```
$(".caracteristicas").html("<%= render 'my_partial' %>")
```

The controller:

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { @caracteristicas = Caracteristica.where(tipo_imovel_id: params[:tipo_imovel_id]) }
  end
end
```

You see? So when I try to render my partial via ajax it complains that it has no `f` variable.
Am I doing this right? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I would just use actual html here.  Try rendering this page with the full code, inspecting it, and just copy/pasting the rendered html into your partial.  I'm sure there's a way to hack it with helpers, but it just seems easier this way.